# Update the list of default applications

Tags: 11.10

How can I have unity in ubuntu 11.10 to remove the names of deinstalled applications from the list of default applications?
I have removed all internet browser applications with software center. They dont disappear from the list of default applications in system information.
In Unity in ubuntu 11.10 there is a bottom for shutdown on the upper menuebar. There you can find system settings. inside that system settings menue there is an icon **"system information"**, where you can find default applications. Application names dont disappear, when you deinstall an application. How can I let this names disappeare?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the list of applications in the open with tab in file properties. You can check ~/.local/share/applications for any left over *.desktop files, these may be the cause of the extra applications. Rather don't just delete the files, first move them and see if it solves your problem

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo update-alternatives --list <group>
sudo update-alternatives --remove <group> <app>
```

where  is the application you removed but still listed in , and  is the alternative name you want to change.

Comment: I think the OP was asking how to change the list of applications presented by tools like `cinnamon-settings default`?